# Animate React component when unmount/leave

Tags: reactjs, animation, velocity.js

I want to use Velocity to fade out a component when the component leaves . I'm calling the callback but there is no animation. What is wrong with the code below?

```
export class Foo extends Component {

      componentWillEnter(cb) {
        cb();
      }

      componentWillLeave(cb) {
         const node = findDOMNode(el);
         Velocity(node, { opacity: 0 }, { duration:200 });
         cb();
      }
}
```

Comment: Velocity tag is irrelevant here, because it's `Apache Velocity is a Java-based template engine`

Comment: @user7294900 You are correct. It was missing the .js on the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on a [GSAP post](https://medium.com/@marcmintel/react-meets-gsap-c6dd82edeb72). The callback needs to be passed to Velocity as the complete function.

```
    export class Foo extends Component {
      componentWillEnter(cb) {
        cb();
      }
      componentWillLeave(cb) {
         const node = findDOMNode(el);
         Velocity(node, { opacity: 0 }, { duration:200, complete: cb });
      }

    ...
    }
```